# Set up a rule from a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

I have to set up a recursive formula for a sequence that gives the number of ways to take out and arrange lego bricks to a wall with the length of 2n knobs.

Some lego bricks have 6-knobs and some has 8-knobs.

I have calculated several values for n.

I have problems setting up a rule from a pattern. I cant even see the pattern from the integers I have.

I have the following values (starting from n = 6) :

1 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 5 - 6 - 10 - 11 - 11 - 16 - 21 - 22 - 27 - 37

Can you see any pattern or could it be that I have calculated wrong somehow? (pretty sure my calculation is correct thought).

Comment: If I understand that right , you basically want to determine the number of solutions $$ 6x+8y=2n$$ in non-negative integers $\ x,y\ $ , right ?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: As a first step, the general solution to $$3x+4y=n$$ is $$(-4t-n\ /\ 3t+n)$$ Now to get non-negative solutions, both entries must be non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:
a(n) = a(n-4) + a(n-3)

Comment: How do you arrive at this recurrence relation ?

Comment: It would help the OP more if you gave a little explanation in addition to, or instead of, the formula, I think.

Comment: @Peter I'm puzzled by your question. Leon asked if we could see any pattern. I did it just by looking at the sequence and by intuition. Do you need anything else?

Comment: You neither showed how this can be seen nor proved that it works for every integer $\ n\ $.

Comment: @Leo It helped me see the pattern! Thank you!!